# create a bat file to run node commands

Tags: node.js, batch-file

I'm trying to run node commands like `npm install` and `node server.js` using a bat file.
I'm planning to put the bat file in the application root folder.
So, the steps I want my bat file to do are:

1. Open command prompt in the same folder.
2. Run `npm install`
3. Run `node server.js`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `.bat` file and you can execute it with the following code

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');
exec('my.bat', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return;
  }
  console.log(stdout);
});
```

**EDIT**

You just create `my.bat` and add the following commands

```
 cd "Your project path"
 npm install
 node server.js
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to how to write the scripts in a bat file. Can you please tell me the scripts to write inside the file so as to run the above commands

Comment: Worked for me. I had to modify the command a bit though. 


```npm install && node server.js```


This script allowed me to run both the commands one after another.

Comment: @Shashank Glad to help!! Please accept the answer if ti really solved your problem